# How to use a wildcard in powershell parameter that doesn't natively support it?

Tags: powershell, parameters, scripting, wildcard

Okay, sorry for the probably noobish question. 
I've been studying PowerShell for a while now, and have run into something I can't quite figure out how to word correctly for google.

In the most basic sense, here is what I'm trying to do.

```
Get-Process -id 76*
```

Now I understand that `-id` will not handle wildcard `*` characters.
If I wanted to in theory use

```
Get-Process -id
```

and create a wildcard script for this purpose, how would I do this? Do i need to create my own function?

I'd like to add as well that PS says specifically the `*` is not a usable character for the `-Name` Parameter, yet I can use this. Is this an error with MS? 
Thank you for any advice in advance!

Comment: Is the idea here to get all processes with IDs that start with `76`? Then @user2864740 has the right idea.

Comment: Re `-Name` parameter and wildcards: They _are_ supported (try `Get-Process -Name Explor*`, for instance). As of PSv5.1, the parameter _description_ (correctly) says so (`Get-Help Get-Process`), even though the `Accept wildcard characters?` line shown with `Get-Help -detailed Get-Process` (incorrectly) contradicts that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [(Where-Object) filter](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Ee177028.aspx) over the Get-Process output.

In this case:

```
Get-Process | where { $_.Id -like '76*' }
```

(`where` is an alias for `Where-Object` cmdlet.)

Comment: So, by piping the output of `Get-Process` , `Where-Object` is essentially filtering the final output of Get-Process? What do the curly bracket signify in this case?

Comment: @cloudnyn3 That is correct. If presence (or rather, absence) of the filter greatly changes the execution time then you are up a creek unless the source itself supports a filter. The curly brackets here create a ["Script Block"](http://www.padisetty.com/2014/05/all-about-powershell-scriptblock.html) which can generally be regarded as a lambda / anonymous function.